# Python 3 - Read csv file with type conversion

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion, namedtuple

I have two problems:

**a) Python csv module could not handle particular csv file properly**

I have the following data in `database.csv`

```
"AAAAAAAA"        ,  5.4817,    0.0000,    0.0000,    0.0000,   65.8370
"n,m-BBBBBBBBB"   ,  1.7897,  675.3787, 1234.7865,   47.0000,   42.0070
```

Take note that there are whitespaces between the double quote and comma.
I used the following script to read the file, the first column will be decoded as `"AAAAAAAA        "`, instead of `"AAAAAAAA"`

```
import csv

def read_csv_data(path):
  with open(path, 'rU') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f_csv:
      yield row

for row in read_csv_data('database.csv'):
  print(row)
```

The output is

```
['AAAAAAAA        ', '  5.4817', '    0.0000', '    0.0000', '    0.0000', '   65.8370']
['n,m-BBBBBBBBB   ', '  1.7897', '  675.3787', ' 1234.7865', '   47.0000', '   42.0070']
```

To remove the whitespaces, I do that

```
import csv

def read_csv_data(path):
  col_type = [str, float, float, float, float, float]
  with open(path, 'rU') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f_csv:
      row = tuple(cast(val.strip()) for cast, val in zip(col_type, row))
      yield row

for row in read_csv_data('database.csv'):
  print(row)
```

The output is now

```
('AAAAAAAA', 5.4817, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 65.8370)
('n,m-BBBBBBBBB', 1.7897, 675.3787, 1234.7865, 47.0, 42.007)
```

**b) Using namedtuple to read in the csv data into memory**

With the same csv file `database.csv`, I use another script:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

def read_csv_data(path):
  col_type = [str, float, float, float, float, float]
  Gas = namedtuple("Gas", ["gas", "sf", "h1", "h2", "h3", "m"])
  with open(path, 'rU') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f_csv:
      row = list(cast(val.strip()) for cast, val in zip(col_type, row))
      for row2 in map(Gas._make, row):
        yield row2


  for row in read_csv_data('database.csv'):
    print(row)
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_dict.py", line 17, in <module>
    for row in read_csv_data('database.csv'):
  File "read_dict.py", line 13, in read_csv_data
    for row2 in map(Gas._make, row):
  File "<string>", line 21, in _make
TypeError: Expected 6 arguments, got 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
for row2 in map(Gas._make, row):
    yield row2
```

You simply want

```
yield Gas._make(row)
```

Right now you're looping over every element in `row` and calling `Gas._make` on it.  That's why you're getting "Expected 6 arguments, got 8" -- you're trying to make a `Gas` instance out of `"AAAAAAAA"`.

After changing this, the output is

```
Gas(gas='AAAAAAAA', sf=5.4817, h1=0.0, h2=0.0, h3=0.0, m=65.837)
Gas(gas='n,m-BBBBBBBBB', sf=1.7897, h1=675.3787, h2=1234.7865, h3=47.0, m=42.007)
```

---

PS: for Python 3, you should open files for use with `csv` using `newline=""`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: For problem a), I have a feeling that csv module does not handle this kind of csv file. I tried `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, and `skipinitialspace=True`.

Comment: I import the csv file `database.csv` into Microsoft Excel, the trailing whitespaces are included. It would mean that it is considered a valid csv file.